# Pages: keyboard shortcut for inserting an equation

Tags: macos, shortcut, pages

Pages has a new feature to add latex equations. As a latex user, I find this extremely useful!

A feature that would make my life even better would be a keyboard shortcut that pushes the "insert" button in the popup window (see the screenshot below). Is it possible to do and how?

Thanks!

[image: The button to push]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to invoke the **Insert** button and press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button to invoke the **Cancel** button.

If you have keyboard navigation enabled (System Preferences app → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls, refer to the screenshot below), it is generally possible to move focus to onscreen control using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and invoke the control currently in focus using either <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key. However, it doesn't appear to be the working in the given case. So the aforementioned keyboard shortcuts should be your recourse.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just found it out by myself :)